# Array empty while performing a for-loop

Tags: c#, unity

I'm working on a massive selection via a 2D rectangle in my RTS project.
For this, I Interate over an array of units, that are within the camera screen.

But somehow, in the loop, the n-th item does seem to contain nothing.
If I call `Debug.Log(UnitsOnScreen[0].ToString());` before the loop, I get this in the console:

> Unit_1(UnityEngine.GameObject) UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

Which basically indicates, that the array does contain something.
But in the loop it doesn't even perform `Debug.Log("Test");`

Any Ideas how I can get rid of this problem?

```
 void LateUpdate()
    {
        UnitsInDrag.Clear();
        if ((UserIsDragging || FinishedDragOnFrame) && UnitsOnScreen.Count > 0){
            Debug.Log(UnitsOnScreen[0].ToString()); // returns something
            for (int i = 0; i > UnitsOnScreen.Count; i++)            {
                Debug.Log("Test"); // no output
                //error somewhere over here
                Debug.Log(UnitsOnScreen[i].ToString());
                GameObject UnitObj = UnitsOnScreen[i] as GameObject;
                Unit UnitScript = UnitObj.GetComponent<Unit>();
                GameObject SelectedObj = UnitObj.transform.FindChild("Selection").gameObject;
                if (!UnitAlreadyInDraggedUnits(UnitObj))
                {
                    if (UnitInsideDrag(UnitScript.ScreenPos))
                    {
                        SelectedObj.SetActive(true);
                        UnitsInDrag.Add(UnitObj);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!UnitAlreadyInDraggedUnits(UnitObj))
                            SelectedObj.SetActive(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (FinishedDragOnFrame)
        {
            FinishedDragOnFrame = false;
            PutDraggedInSelectedUnits();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Array does not have `Count` property. Did you mean some other collection perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure you by

```
for (int i = 0; i > UnitsOnScreen.Count; i++)
```

meant

```
for (int i = 0; i < UnitsOnScreen.Count; i++)
```